# Getting decimal number from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know something similar has already been asked, but I'm having some trouble to get a decimal number that come from keyboard.

My Java code in the onCreate method should be:

```
textS0 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editS0);
Button btn_S0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getS0);

btn_S0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //how should I get here the number from keyboard?
        //I think  I should be something like
        //double S0=textS0.getText()....
    }
});
```

And that's what my XML file contains

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/editS0"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       android:hint="@string/S0"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
<Button
       android:id="@+id/getS0"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/setS0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You'll have to parse the string to a double: [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: when you do getText() it returns you String, just do a simple Double.parseDouble() to get your desired value

Comment: try{Double.parseDouble(textS0.getText().toString())}catch(NumberFormatException e){e.printStacktrace();}

Comment: @ChorWaiChun, [`EditText.getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) returns an [`Editable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) object that itself contains the content. You should call `EditText.getText().toString()` to retrieve the juicy String innards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do this:

```
double S0 = Double.parseDouble(textS0.getText().toString());
```

Comment: If string is empty, causes `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542079/java-lang-numberformatexception-empty-string

Answer (score 3):

```
textS0=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editS0);
Button btn_S0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.getS0);

btn_S0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(View v)
{

           double S0 = Double.parseDouble(textS0.getText().toString());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May b you face null pointer exception in string so try this....

1. get the number decimal from edittext using this

   ```
      Double BText=ParseDouble(String.valueOf(edittext.getText()));
   ```
2. after that paste this code.. it prevents you from null pointer exception

   ```
   double ParseDouble(String strNumber) {
   if (strNumber != null && strNumber.length() > 0) {
       try {
           return Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
       } catch(Exception e) {
           return -1;
       }
   }
   else return 0;
   }
   ```