# My Android program has "stopped working". Debugging issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, widget

This is my Main Activity.  I've used Log.d to get it down to where it stops running, which is at onCreate4.  I'm not sure why it stops in the getReferences section.  I run the program in the emulator, but it tells me automatically that my program has stopped working.

```
package com.example.carloanbuddy4;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnEditorActionListener, OnItemSelectedListener, OnFocusChangeListener,
        OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private TextView payment;
    private TextView interest;
    private EditText principle;
    private TextView interestText;
    private CheckBox interestBox;
    private EditText years;
    private TextView apr;
    Button plusbutton;
    Button minusbutton;
    private static String TAG = "CAR";
    private Spinner period;
    private double aprPercent;
    private int t;





    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate1");
        this.getReferences();
        this.setListeners();        
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void getReferences() {
        payment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paymentLabel);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate2");
        interest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.interestLabel);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate3");
        apr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aprLabel);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate4");
        aprPercent = Double.parseDouble(apr.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate5");
        interestText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.interestText);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate6");
        interestBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate7");
        interestBox.setChecked(false);
        principle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.principleEditText);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate8");
        years = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yearsEditText);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate9");
        period = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate10");
        minusbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minusbutton);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate11");
        plusbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate12");
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.options,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        period.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate13");


        // principle.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "getReferences principle: " + principle.getText()
                + " years:" + years.getText());

    }

    public void setListeners() { // where the event being consumed will be
                                    // responding
        principle.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        principle.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        years.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        years.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        interestBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        period.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Log.d(TAG, "setListeners principle: " + principle.getText() + " years:"
                + years.getText());
    }

    public void setPeriodValue() {
        if (period.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Monthly")) {
            t = 12;
        } else if (period.getSelectedItem().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Quarterly")) {
            t = 4;
        } else if (period.getSelectedItem().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Annually")) {
            t = 1;
        }
    }

    public void updateResults() {
        double dblPrinciple = Double
                .parseDouble(principle.getText().toString());
        double dblYears = Double.parseDouble(years.getText().toString());

        double num, denom, dblPayment;
        double r = aprPercent / 100;
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        NumberFormat curr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        apr.setText(nf.format(aprPercent));
        setPeriodValue();
        num = (r / t);
        denom = (1 - Math.pow((1 + num), (t * -dblYears)));
        dblPayment = dblPrinciple * (num / denom);
        payment.setText(curr.format(dblPayment));
        interest.setText(curr
                .format((dblPayment * t * dblYears) - dblPrinciple));

    }

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasfocus) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Focus Change principle: " + principle.getText() + " years"
                + years.getText());
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.principleEditText:
        case R.id.yearsEditText:
            updateResults();
        default:
            updateResults();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(interestBox.isChecked()) {
            interest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            interestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            interest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            interestText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (interestBox.isChecked()!=true){
            interest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            interestText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            interest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            interestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        updateResults();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        updateResults();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.minusbutton:
            if (aprPercent == 1) {
                break;
            } else {
                aprPercent = aprPercent - 1.0;
                updateResults();
                break;
            }
        case R.id.plusbutton:
            if (aprPercent == 20) {
                break;
            } else {
                aprPercent = aprPercent + 1.0;
                updateResults();
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        updateResults();
    }

}
```

This is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.carloanbuddy4.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:shrinkColumns="0, 1"
        android:stretchColumns="0, 1">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/principleText"
                android:ems="5"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/principleEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
                android:text="@string/principle_entered"
                android:textSize="12sp" >
                 <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/yearsText"
                android:ems="5"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/yearsEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:ems="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:labelFor="@id/yearsEditText"
                android:text="@string/years_entered"
                android:textSize="12sp" >

                 <requestFocus />
            </EditText>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:padding="5dp"
                 android:text="@string/aprText"
                 android:ems="5"
                 android:textSize="12sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/aprLabel"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:ems="5"
                 android:labelFor="@id/aprLabel"
                 android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                 android:textSize="20sp" >

             </TextView>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/minusbutton"
                 android:onClick="onClick"
                 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/minus_button" />

            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/plusbutton"
                 android:onClick="onClick"
                 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/plus_button" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView4"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:padding="5dp"
                 android:text="@string/periodText"
                 android:textSize="12sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

               <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />



        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:checked="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="@string/interest_checkbox"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paymentText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/paymentText"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paymentLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/payment_total"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/interestText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/interestText"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/interestLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/interest_total"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

         <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

          <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="@string/save_checkbox"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
         </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Double.parseDouble(apr.getText().toString());, string is empty, exception is thrown.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542079/java-lang-numberformatexception-empty-string

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how I would fix that issue.

Comment: To find out where it stops running, don't put in log statemtents like you did. Use the stacktrace. This stacktrace contains sufficient information so you can solve the problem (either by deduction, or Googling the exception). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

It think you're calling apr.getText().toString() but neither in the XML file nor the java code before I see that TextFile has any text so i guess it's returning null and then you have a NullPointException. You could check that.

If not, try this:

When calling getReferences() method add a try-catch block so that your onCreate method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate1");

    try {
        this.getReferences();
    } catch (Exception e){
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        Log.i("Exception", errors.toString());
    }

    this.setListeners();        
}
```

Then, in the LogCat window, click on the green  cross button (+). In the field Filter Name use the name you wish, in "by Log Tag" type Exception and in by log level select info.

This way you'll filter all the messages and will keep only the stack trace. Check which exception is being thrown and if you don't figure out the solution you can always come back here and update the question with the the new info you've just achieved.

I hope it helps.