# Buffered Reader Character Input Not Woring

Tags: java, bufferedreader

This program does not give a compiling error, but gives a run-time error while taking character input, if there are any compiling errors, I use BlueJ (I know it sucks but School so...)

```
import java.io.*;

class Buffered
{
    public static void reader() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
        String s = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your character");
        char y = (char)br.read();

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your double");
        double d = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

        System.out.println(y+s+d);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime error?  I'm not savvy in Java, but you may need to cast your `d` as a string on the `println`

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException;

Comment: empty String (in.sun.misc.FloatingDecimal)

Comment: Could you also maybe correct the code and send, that will be gr8

Comment: Please see the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21542133/902874

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542079/java-lang-numberformatexception-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Please Enter Your character");
char y = (char)br.read();
```

So, the user enters for example `A`, and then presses enter. The above line of code only reads the character 'A'.

```
System.out.println("Please Enter Your double");
double d = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
```

Then the above line reads the rest of the line, right after the last character that has been read: 'A'. Since there is no more character between 'A' and the end of the line, `readLine()` returns an empty string, that you try to parse to a Double, hence the exception.

Comment: You read the end of the line after the char, and then you read the next line and parse it to a double.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit messy when you run the code, however as JB Nizet said: `read()` reads only 1st char and `readLine()` is trying to read the rest of the line which is empty.

The solution I found was:

Read char at the end. Look at the code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Buffered {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
        String s = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your double");
        String g = br.readLine();
        double d = 0;
        try {
            d = Double.parseDouble(g);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Please Enter Your character");
        char y = (char)br.read();

        System.out.println(y+s+d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do : After reading a character, try to read a line.

char c = (char)br.read();

br.readLine();

As readLine() method read a line of text.
A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

But read() method reads a single character from this buffered reader and return it as an integer value.

Here, As we click "enter" after inputting a character value, the double variable try to process "\n", which causes "NumberFormatException".

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you're doing this?