# How to validate to enter only decimal numbers or whole numbers,but not the symbols alone.(android)

Tags: java, android

I need to validate my edit text, I google it and find some links,but still couldn't get what I really want.

I need to validate the edit text input in android to allow decimal numbers,whole numbers and positive numbers,It won't allow only the characters (`.`,`/`,`$`) and spaces.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
  />
```

I tried like this,but couldn't enter decimal number also.

I refer this link also http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, still couldn't do.

Comment: No,I need to enter the budget amount ,so that ,I can enter budget amount in decimal number also.but if the user enter only fullstop in the edit text or if the editext have space ,I need to show error message,

Comment: No,I don't need to limit the decimal numbers,user can enter any decimal number,user can enter `223.3` like this,but user can't enter `.`  (fullstop) only as the input.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if it is possible in your scenario to validate the text against a regular expression, but you could use this expression to validate it:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

It will allow full numbers (like 1234) and decimal number (like 1234.5678) but not something like `1234.`, `.5678` or just a dot (or any other symbol).

Comment: If this answer has helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, controlling the min and max input chars and limiting it to a decimal value.

In your xml:

```
<EditText
    .../
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="12"/>
```

Then in your java, validate the length, you could also validate range, but would need to parse the edittext value.
To test for a value that cannot only contain a fullstop and ask for a min input.

```
if(editText.getText().length()<2)
// throw error.
```

Also there is these two question and answers:

[Limit Decimal Places in Android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext)

[Getting decimal number from edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506756/getting-decimal-number-from-edittext)

Comment: length<2 means what? it's just a value or what?